# ghci won't interpret file but cabal build succeeds?

Tags: haskell, compilation, cabal, ghci

When I load a certain file in `ghci` / `cabal repl`, I get the following error message:

```
No instance for (Control.Monad.Trans.Class.MonadTrans
                   (EitherT Error))
  arising from a use of ‘lift’
```

However, `EitherT a` is definitely an instance of `MonadTrans`; it's part of the package. `cabal build` succeeds; too. It seems `ghci` and `cabal repl` don't know about `EitherT` typeclass instances (`liftIO` produces a similar error) for some reason (but `cabal build` is happy with it)?

Has anyone encountered anything like this before?

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT:

Yup; most of the instances are missing:

```
λ :i EitherT
type role EitherT nominal representational nominal
newtype EitherT e (m :: * -> *) a
  = EitherT {runEitherT :: m (Either e a)}
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Either’
instance Eq (m (Either e a)) => Eq (EitherT e m a)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Either’
instance Monad m => Monad (EitherT e m)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Either’
instance Monad m => Functor (EitherT e m)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Either’
instance Ord (m (Either e a)) => Ord (EitherT e m a)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Either’
instance Read (m (Either e a)) => Read (EitherT e m a)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Either’
instance Show (m (Either e a)) => Show (EitherT e m a)
  -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Either’
λ
```

*However*, if I run `cabal get either` to get the source code for the package, and open *that* in `cabal repl`, it *does* have all the instances. So... uh... why doesn't it know about those instances when I import the package instead of loading the source code?

EDIT5:

Ok, this is seriously weird. Running `ghci` (*not* `cabal repl` inside the `either-4.3.3.2` source directory and then running `:l src/Control/Monad/Trans/Either.hs` produces missing typeclass instance errors for `EitherT`, namely `MonadTrans`

```
λ :l src/Control/Monad/Trans/Either.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Control.Monad.Trans.Either ( src/Control/Monad/Trans/Either.hs, interpreted )

src/Control/Monad/Trans/Either.hs:287:14:
    Could not deduce (transformers-0.3.0.0:Control.Monad.Trans.Class.MonadTrans
                        (EitherT e))
```

Comment: Can you post the full code that is causing this error?

Comment: My guess, which wouldn't be visible from just the code, is that you have two versions of `transformers` installed: A newer one that is loaded directly by GHCi and an older one that is used by some other package you have installed. Then `MonadTrans` from one gets mixed with `EitherT` from the other, which it knows nothing about. `cabal` makes sure to use one consistent version.

Comment: @Ørjan-johansen, that sounds pretty likely -- it was working and then stopped and I feel like I ran a `cabal` install in the middle or something... I tried `ghc-pkg unregister` on `transformers` (and maybe `mtl`?) and re-installed it but it didn't fix it. Any idea how else to test if your hypothesis is correct?

Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Eek, I'm not sure unregistering `transformers`/`mtl` is wise, you may break other packages that come with GHC and that *need* a particular version. To check if there are two versions installed, use `ghc-pkg list ...`. And you can give GHCi a `-package` flag (or use `:set`) to force a version to be used, but I suspect that won't work if it's implicitly used by two other packages. Also, everyone seems to be recommending cabal sandboxes these days (I'm a bit behind on that...)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen - Aw, shoot; I was so hopeful about that one. Yeah; there's only one instance of `transformers` / `mtl` installed. Probably should've done a cabal sandbox right from the start.

Comment: Son of a gun. @ØrjanJohansen, you were right -- I did have two different versions installed, but I didn't see it in `ghc-pkg list` because I didn't scroll up enough; there are two sets of packages; one in `/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.8.3-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-7.8.3/package.conf.d` and one in `~/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-7.8.3/package.conf.d`. Why, I have no idea :P

The fix was to initialize a sandbox and run `cabal install --only-dependencies`.

*phew*; this was quite a thing to track down...

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, post what you said above about two different versions being installed if you'd like and I'll mark it as the accepted answer ;)

Comment: I just had a slightly embarassing realization: `EitherT` is defined in the `either` package, not `transformers`. (That makes like *3* differently named slight variations of that type I know about, although to be fair `ErrorT` is deprecated.) The rest seems to be correct so I'll clean it up a bit and make it an answer.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, indeed, it appears that the main difference between `EitherT` and `ExceptT` is that `EitherT` uses GHC extensions (notably `FlexibleContexts`, but maybe others) to produce instances with weaker constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, which wouldn't be visible from just the code, is that you have two versions of `transformers` installed: A newer one that is loaded directly by GHCi and an older one that is used by the installed `either` package. Or possibly even more packages are involved through indirect dependencies.

Then `MonadTrans` from one gets mixed with `EitherT` from the other, which knows nothing about it.

`cabal`, on the other hand, makes sure to use one consistent version.

To check if there are two versions installed, use

```
ghc-pkg list transformers
```

You can give GHCi a `-package` flag (or use `:set`) to force a version to be used, although that will only affect loaded files, not installed packages.

Also, everyone seems to be recommending `cabal` sandboxes these days to avoid such problems.